# WPF Borderless window Maximized issue on different resolutions

Tags: wpf

I have borderless window in WPF which is using some custom styles. I am using the multiple monitors with different resolutions to show the application. When application moves from smaller resolution to biggeest resolution monitor the application is not properly maximized and some area of the screen show empty. how can i make it maximized on all the resolutions?

Thanks

Comment: I have this working on my app. You may have absolute widths and heights set somewhere in the window preventing it from growing on the larger monitor.

Comment: I am using borderless window in WPF and i am using the Native methods to maximized the screen. Is this could be an issue?

Comment: I assume by borderless you mean WindowStyle="None". I used this then implemented my own double click events and maximise button on a custom window header in order to maximise. They still only call Me.WindowState = Windows.WindowState.Maximized.

Comment: I have come through this URL
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/540394/maximized-window-does-not-cover-working-area-after-screen-setup-change
This is the issue in the WPF which i am facing, is their any workaround for this issue. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: According to the issue it only happens when you detach the monitor via windows and the WPF window automatically jumps to the other screen. Is this what you are doing or are you just moving it across? You did not mention detaching a monitor in the original question.

Comment: No, actually i drag the screen to the second monitor through mouse.

Comment: How do you go about maximising the window after dragging it to the other monitor. Have you got sample code to show what you do when trying to maximise it.

Comment: Dim hMonitor As IntPtr = CustomMethods.MonitorFromWindow(Me.currentHwndSource.Handle, CustomMethods.MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST)
        Dim monitorinfo As New CustomMethods.MONITORINFO()
        CustomMethods.GetMonitorInfo(hMonitor, monitorinfo)
        minmaxinfo.ptMaxPosition.x = Math.Abs(monitorinfo.rcMonitor.left - monitorinfo.rcWork.left)
        minmaxinfo.ptMaxPosition.y = Math.Abs(monitorinfo.rcMonitor.top - monitorinfo.rcWork.top)
        minmaxinfo.ptMaxSize.x = Math.Abs(monitorinfo.rcWork.left - monitorinfo.rcWork.right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using WindowChrome class to draw window. This feature allows to redraw non-client area of a window. This mean You can have borderless window acting as SingleBordered one. It resolve a lot of problems with custom windows.
If You target .NET 4.5, just type:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <WindowChrome/>
</WindowChrome.WindowChrome>

<Grid>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

For .NET below 4.5 You have to reference Microsoft.Windows.Shell.dll and then use e.g. shell:WindowChrome for the same results.

Also don't use

```
WindowState = Windows.WindowState.Maximized
```

instead type e.g.

```
<Button x:Name="buttonMaximize" Command="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemCommands.MaximizeWindowCommand}}">
```

which use default Windows action to maximize window with animation and perfect scaling.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it.

```
<Window WindowState="Maximized">
</Window>
```

Comment: No it's not working. Only the primary screen shows the maximized screen of application. but when i drag to secondary screen which has bigger resolutions. it won't work

Comment: that wont work. But try to drag it to the secondary screen then close that window and reopen it. Then it will maximize right ?

Comment: No it's not working if we close the window and reopen it again. please have a look in to following issue, which i am facing https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/540394/maximized-window-does-not-cover-working-area-after-screen-setup-change