# Dual monitor issue for WPF Borderless window maximization

Tags: wpf

I am using borderless custom window in WPF and it works fine on one monitor but one i drag the window to second monitor which has higer resolution the window is not properly maximized and some space of monitor remains empty. This issue is described in the following community blog, is their any workaround of this problem ?

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/540394/maximized-window-does-not-cover-working-area-after-screen-setup-change

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF Borderless window Maximized issue on different resolutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634099/wpf-borderless-window-maximized-issue-on-different-resolutions)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have no alternative. You have to work with low level windows API.

See http://blog.onedevjob.com/2010/10/19/fixing-full-screen-wpf-windows/ for a better trattation of the arguments.

Or Have you checked the `Screen` class ?

Comment: I have applied this solution as well but even it does not work as well.

Comment: No i haven't checked the screen class, would you please tell anything about this or share any reference. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answer I gave on this thread on Borderless windows.  The answer to your multi-monitor problem exists within that code.

[WPF Borderless Window issues: Aero Snap & Maximizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422666/wpf-borderless-window-issues-aero-snap-maximizing/48626016#48626016)